# Postpone function execution syntactically

Tags: python, numpy, generator, decorator

I've got a quite extensive simulation tool written in `python`, which requires the user to call functions to set up the environment in a strict order since `np.ndarrays` are at first created (and changed by appending etc.) and afterwards memory views to specific cells of these arrays are defined.
Currently each part of the environment requires around 4 different function calls to be set up, with easily `>> 100` parts.
Thus I need to combine each part's function calls by **syntactically** (not based on timers) postponing the execution of some functions until all preceding functions have been executed, while still maintaining the strict order to be able to use memory views.

Futhermore all functions to be called by the user use [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) style keyword-only arguments to reduce the probability of input-errors **and** all are **instance methods** with `self` as the first parameter, with `self` containing the references to the arrays to construct the memory views to.

My current implementation is using `list`s to store the functions and the `dict` for each function's keyworded arguments. This is shown here, omitting the class and self parameters to make it short:

```
def fun1(*, x, y):  # easy minimal example function 1
    print(x * y)
def fun2(*, x, y, z):  # easy minimal example function 2
    print((x + y) / z)

fun_list = []  # list to store the functions and kwargs
fun_list.append([fun1, {'x': 3.4, 'y': 7.0}])  # add functions and kwargs
fun_list.append([fun2, {'x':1., 'y':12.8, 'z': np.pi}])
fun_list.append([fun2, {'x':0.3, 'y':2.4, 'z': 1.}])

for fun in fun_list:
    fun[0](**fun[1])
```

What I'd like to implement is using a `decorator` to postpone the function execution by adding a `generator`, to be able to pass all arguments to the functions as they are called, but not execute them, as shown below:

```
def postpone(myfun):  # define generator decorator
    def inner_fun(*args, **kwargs):
        yield myfun(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner_fun

fun_list_dec = []  # list to store the decorated functions
fun_list_dec.append(postpone(fun1)(x=3.4, y=7.0))  # add decorated functions
fun_list_dec.append(postpone(fun2)(x=1., y=12.8, z=np.pi))
fun_list_dec.append(postpone(fun2)(x=0.3, y=2.4, z=1.))

for fun in fun_list_dec:  # execute functions
    next(fun)
```

Which is the best (most pythonic) method to do so? Are there any drawbacks?
And most important: Will my references to `np.ndarrays` passed to the functions within `self` still be a reference, so that the memory addresses of these arrays are still correct when executing the functions, **if** the memory addresses change **in between** saving the function calls to a list (or being decorated) and executing them?
Execution speed does not matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a generators here doesn't make much sense. You are essentially simulating partial-application. Therefore, this seems like a use-case for `functools.partial`. Since you are sticking with key-word only arguments, this will work just fine:

```
In [1]: def fun1(*, x, y):  # easy minimal example function 1
   ...:     print(x * y)
   ...: def fun2(*, x, y, z):  # easy minimal example function 2
   ...:     print((x + y) / z)
   ...:

In [2]: from functools import partial

In [3]: fun_list = []

In [4]: fun_list.append(partial(fun1, x=3.4, y=7.0))

In [5]: fun_list.append(partial(fun2, x=1., y=12.8, z=3.14))

In [6]: fun_list.append(partial(fun2, x=0.3, y=2.4,z=1.))

In [7]: for f in fun_list:
   ...:     f()
   ...:
23.8
4.3949044585987265
2.6999999999999997
```

You don't *have* to use `functools.partial` either, you can do your partial application "manually", just to demonstrate:

```
In [8]: fun_list.append(lambda:fun1(x=5.4, y=8.7))

In [9]: fun_list[-1]()
46.98
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look into it, especially the use of `lambda` looks great. Will array references be updated before execution?

Comment: @Scotty1- I'm not sure what you mean. Why would they be updated?

Comment: Ok, just tested it and it works great for `lambda` but not for `functools.partial`. I know it is quite a special case thus I didn't expect it to work for anything else besides my version using `kwargs`. But even better that it works with the extremely short and intuitive `lambda`! To show you what I mean I'll have to post an answer, otherwise code formatting will be too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Since for commenting the code would be too complicated and it is based on juanpa.arrivillaga's answer, I'll add a full post with a short explanation what I mean by updating the reference to the arrays:

```
def fun1(*, x, y):  # easy minimal example function 1
    print(x * y)

arr = np.random.rand(5)
f1_lam = lambda:fun1(x=arr, y=5.)
f1_par = partial(fun1, x=arr, y=5.)
f1_lam()  # Out[01]: [0.55561103 0.9962626  3.60992174 2.55491852 3.9402079 ]
f1_par()  # Out[02]: [0.55561103 0.9962626  3.60992174 2.55491852 3.9402079 ]

# manipulate array so that the memory address changes and
# passing as reference is "complicated":
arr = np.append(arr, np.ones((2,1)))
f1_lam()  # Out[03]: [0.55561103 0.9962626  3.60992174 2.55491852 3.9402079  5. 5.]
f1_par()  # Out[02]: [0.55561103 0.9962626  3.60992174 2.55491852 3.9402079 ]
```

The behaviour of `lambda` is exactly what I was looking for in this question.

My examples with `dict` and `decorator`s don't work, as well as `functools.partial`. Any idea why `lambda` is working? And just out of interest: Would there be any way to update the references to the arrays in the `dict` so that it would also work this way?

Comment: This is working because the lambda function references the global `arr` name. This is probably not a good approach. If, as you say, you are creating views of your array, these will break when you use something like `.append`

Comment: So, fundamentally this approach relies on mutating global state, which smells of bad design. Why can't your subsequent functions receive new arrays as arguments? Anyway, it is critical to understand that Python *does not* support pass-by-reference semantics

Comment: Yep, that is bad design. The problem here is: My current code avoids this situation by asserting a strict execution order, thus no postponing is needed. But I reached a point where usability becomes more and more important. This clashes with the strict order, since keeping the strict order would require the user to type hundreds of statements in the correct order, which is prone to errors and not really nice. Thus I was looking for a way to combine multiple statements and be able to pass them in random order.

Comment: This would reduce the amount of statements to about one fifth AND allow the user to easily combine them into importable modules. To avoid the case of bad design while still being able to benefit from postponing statements, I am currently rewriting my whole program. I could be using `partial` or `lambda` to do so. Is there any reason not to go with `lambda` as long as I avoid mutating global state?